# What’s causing the linear-gradient to degrade in image quality when placed on Blogger?

Tags: svg, blogger

After it is placed on Blogger, the hue of the linear gradient drops/lessens dramatically.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Is there any possible way I can fix this so it stays the same?

https://jsfiddle.net/cs311dLn/1/

https://testpage34567.blogspot.com/

The linear-gradient in the images are the 2 lines in the middle going down.

**.html**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Ay1.png)

**Blogger:**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLw7t.png)

```
  <svg width="260" height="194">
    <defs>
      <clippath id="circleView">
        <circle cx="130" cy="97" r="85" fill="orange"></circle>
      </clippath>
    </defs>
    <image x="40" y="7" width="180" height="180" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/BO6KOvw.jpg" clip-path="url(#circleView)"> </image>
    <image x="40" y="7" width="180" height="180" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/4HJbzEq.png"></image>

    <svg width="260" height="194">
      <defs>
        <lineargradient id="MyGradient">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="transparent"></stop>
          <stop offset="31.9%" stop-color="transparent"></stop>
          <stop offset="31.9%" stop-color="#0059dd"></stop>
          <stop offset="33.2%" stop-color="#0059dd"></stop>
          <stop offset="33.2%" stop-color="transparent"></stop>
          <stop offset="66.8%" stop-color="transparent"></stop>
          <stop offset="66.8%" stop-color="#0059dd"></stop>
          <stop offset="68.1%" stop-color="#0059dd"></stop>
          <stop offset="68.1%" stop-color="transparent"></stop>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="transparent"></stop>
        </lineargradient>
      </defs>

      <rect fill="url(#MyGradient)" x="0" y="0" width="260" height="194"></rect>
    </svg>
  </svg>
```